# IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint while logging in user using django tasty pie

Tags: django, tastypie

This is my UserLoginResource:

```
class UserLoginResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        object_class = User
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['post','get']
        include_resource_uri = False
        resource_name = 'login'
        excludes = ['is_active','is_staff','is_superuser']
        authentication = SillyAuthentication()
        authorization = SillyAuthorization()

    def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            bundle = super(UserLoginResource, self).obj_create(bundle,request,**kwargs)
            bundle.obj.set_password(bundle.data.get('password'))
            bundle.obj.set_username(bundle.data.get('username'))
            bundle.obj.save() 
            return bundle
        except IntegrityError:
            raise BadRequest('The username exists')

    def dehydrate(self,bundle):
        bundle.data['custom_field'] = "Whatever you want"
        return bundle
```

When I do post with username and password that already exists, it gives a 500 error saying Integrity error, and that the username already exists.

1. How do I log-in?
2. Even if there is an error(let's say the username doesn't exist, how do I prettify the error response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. with this code you are creating User object and not login
2. see tastypie.validation